# Reading delimited file columns as lists, returning rows instead

Tags: python, list, pandas, csv, weighted-average

I have a large .txt file and I'd like to read each column as a list. The file has 9 columns of delimited floats, the first line (of a few thousand) is:

```
0.49406565E-323  0.29532530E+003  0.89244837E+001  0.20901651E-002  0.34989878E+001  0.11594090E+000  0.34025716E-001  0.33723126E+001  0.27954433E+000  0.80757378E-001  0.50813056E+001
```

I'm reading my file like this:

```
colnames = ['weight', 'likelihood', 'A_0', 'w_0', 'p_0', 'A_1', 'w_1', 'p_1', 'A_2', 'w_2', 'p_2']
data = pandas.read_csv('data.txt', names=colnames)

weights = data.weight.tolist()
A_0     = data.A_0.tolist()
```

The first column is the weight, and the rest are parameters and I want to perform a weighted average calculation of all the parameters with respect to their weights.

But if I print `weights`, for example, it returns the entire file, and `weights[0]` is the first row of the file.

For completion my weighted average would be something like:

```
weighted_A_0 = numpy.average(A_0, weights=weights)
```

Perhaps there's a neater way with pandas and numpy?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default `pd.read_csv` looks for comma separated, but you can specify your delimiter using the `sep` argument eg:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', names=colnames, sep='\t')
```

for tab separated - would that help?

---

### Final:

turns out it was `'  '` delimited so we made it work with

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', names=colnames, sep='\s+')
```

Comment: Nope, just tried it, I get the exact same results, thanks though!

Comment: what's your file separated by? the snipet looks like 2 spaces? have you tried that? (`sep='  '`)

Comment: I assumed it was tab separated, but with `(sep = '  ')` it worked, I do get this error though: `ParserWarning: Falling back to the 'python' engine because the 'c' engine does not support regex separators (separators > 1 char and different from '\s+' are interpreted as regex); you can avoid this warning by specifying engine='python'.`

Comment: a) that's probably fine and b) you could use `sep='\s+'` as that should do the same thing.

Comment: from the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html): >The C engine is faster while the python engine is currently more feature-complete.

Comment: ah nice, your (b) answer worked better with no errors, cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Since you have not passed any separator to `read_csv` function, it takes comma as a default delimiter. Your file `data.txt` doesn't contain any comma, hence it takes the whole data into first column (weight).

```
data = pandas.read_csv('data.txt', names=colnames, delim_whitespace=True)
```

> **delim_whitespace : boolean, default False**
>
> Specifies whether or not
>   whitespace (e.g. ' ' or '    ') will be used as the sep.
>
> **Equivalent to setting sep='\s+'**. If this option is set to True, nothing should be
>   passed in for the delimiter parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(r'C:/input_data.txt') as f:
   lines = f.read().splitlines()
   lines = [line.split() for line in lines]
   #print lines
labels = [column labels]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(lines , columns=labels)
```